# Link from ticket_uri is opening a blank page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, uri, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I've got a php page that is pulling events from a facebook fan page.  If I open an incognito window (or log out of facebook) and then click the link, a blank page opens.  My guess is there's something to do with access tokens, permissions of the FB app and permissions to the page.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The ticket_uri tries to open a link like this: http://www.facebook.com/ajax/events/ticket.php?event_id=147884225370550&action_source=12. If logged in, it seems like this is auto-forwarded to the actual ticket link in the event.

Here is page I'm working on: http://danagould.com/live.php.  It's pulling from the facebook page officialdanagould

```
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

//requiring FB PHP SDK
require 'fb-sdk/src/facebook.php';

//initializing keys
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'MYAPPID',
    'secret' => 'MYAPPSECRET',
    'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

$fql    =   "SELECT name, pic, start_time, end_time, location, description, eid, has_profile_pic, venue, ticket_uri
            FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 175890419184371 AND start_time > now() ) 
            ORDER BY start_time asc";

$param  =   array(
'method'    => 'fql.query',
'query'     => $fql,
'callback'  => ''
);

$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

//looping through retrieved data
foreach( $fqlResult as $keys => $values ){

    $convertedtime = strtotime($values['start_time']);
    $start_date = date( 'F j', $convertedtime );

    $content = $values['description'];


    //printing the data
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td width='8%'>";
        if ( $values['has_profile_pic'] == FALSE) {
            echo "<img src=img/spacer.gif width='100%'/>";
        } else {
            echo "<img src={$values['pic']}  width='100%'/>";
        }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td width='2%'></td>";
    echo "<td width='18%' class='tourdate'>{$start_date}</td>";
    echo "<td width='49%'>";
    echo "<table><tbody><tr><td class='tourlocation'>{$values['name']}</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td class='poddesc'><p class='poddesc'>At {$values['location']}</p></td></tr></tbody></table>";
    echo "<td width='23%' class='getickets'>";
    echo "<a href = " . $values['ticket_uri'] . ">Get Tickets</a>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr height='5px'></tr>";

}

?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe this is true of any event on Facebook with ticket_uri specified.  So I don't think it's anything you're doing wrong.  I logged a bug with facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1465099450371691/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cookies to false or set $fql globally. In addition what are you stating in callback